# small webapp in Java+MySQL: GAE vs EC2

Tags: java, mysql, google-app-engine, amazon-ec2, cloud-hosting

I want to develop a small web application (small=4 entities, 3 html forms, login, email and cron) but I've got no server to host it. I'd like to work in Java and MySQL so I've got the following dillema:

1) If I go to GAE I'll have to use something other than MySQL. Is it worth learning this "something other" and what could that be?

2) If I go to EC2 I'll be able to use whatever I want but I'll inherit all the sysadmin time costs. Is it worth the burden?

Also, which of those is cheaper assuming that I have 0 visitors per day?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your requirements, both GAE and AWS should be free (see [GAE free quota](http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/billing.html#freequota) and the quite new [free usage tier for AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/free/)). Thus money shouldn't be worth considering but time certainly is. What do you prefer? Spending time learning new things or spending time administering what you're already used to?

Getting started on GAE isn't that complicated. Hence I'd suggest that you simply give it a try. If you don't feel very comfortable, it shouldn't be too difficult to move to EC2 (or any root server).

Comment: GAE it is then. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Great choice. 24 hours later and I'm up and running. For persistence I use objectify.

Comment: @cherouvim congrats, but that's what I expected anyway. have fun ;)